Formatting date in reference apa7 (3 december 2024)
I have a problem getting the correct format of the date for Swedish apa7. I need: (3 december 2024). Currently I'm using:
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{
    editors = Red\adddot, 
    edition = uppl\adddot,
    nodate = u.\addabbrvspace å.\adddot}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

When using date = {2024-12-03} in the bib file I get:

(2024, 3. december)

If I'm instead specifying the times seperately using year = {2024}, month = {12} and day = {03} I get the following when compiling:

(2024 december)

The bibliographic entry is as follows:
@online{key,
    author = {First Second},
    title = {Title},
    note = {PowerPoint-presentation},
    url = {https://}, 
    year = {2024},
    month = {12},
    day = {03},
    organization = {School name},
}

What can I do to change the format of the date to the desired (3 december 2024)?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Please edit your posting to provide an example of a bibliographic entry that generates the issue you wish to fix. That'll facilitate testing and proposing solutions.

@online{key,     author = {First Second},     title = {Title},     note = {PowerPoint-presentation},     url = {https://},      year = {2024},     month = {12},     date = {03},     organization = {School name}, }

Should it be date = {03} or day = {03}?

day. I've changed it now, but it still doesn't work.

Only date = {2024-12-03}, is valid input. day is not a valid biblatex field and year and month are legacy fields for BibTeX support that can only be used to specify, well, year and month. If you need more granular dates or other ISO date features, you must use the date field.
The APA date format is slightly idiosyncratic. I think it almost makes sense when you come from an American mm/dd/yyyy date format background, but for the rest of the world it probably just looks weird.
You can try the following, which restores biblatex's normal long date format for Swedish.
\documentclass[swedish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{
  editors = {Red\adddot}, 
  edition = {uppl\adddot},
  nodate  = {u.\addabbrvspace å.\adddot}
}


\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{swedish}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongextra#1#2#3#4{%
    % As per 10.1, Articles only have year
    \ifboolexpr{ (test {\ifentrytype{article}}
                  or (test {\ifentrytype{inbook}} and not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}))
                 and not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{nonacademic}} }
      {\clearfield{labelmonth}%
       \clearfield{labelday}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{#4}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#4}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\iffieldbibstring{#2}{\bibcplstring{\thefield{#2}}}{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibncpstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\thefield{#1}}%
    \printfield{extradate}%
  }%
}
\makeatother



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{key,
  author       = {First Second},
  title        = {Title},
  note         = {PowerPoint-presentation},
  date         = {2024-12-03},
  organization = {School name},
  urldate      = {2024-12-03},
  url          = {https://example.com},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


If there is a translation of APA to Swedish that can claim to be at least "semi-official" (maybe by a local APA equivalent) and they use a different date format, you might want to open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues to suggest a change.

Wow thank you, you are an angel! Good to know that day is not a valid entry. Is github the "official" website for update suggestions in LaTeX?

@fner Some packages are developed at GitHub, but not all. Usually you can find the address to submit bugs and suggestions on the CTAN page of the package (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) or in the documentation (which is also available via CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf)
